# Azure Release Pipeline after Build specific stage

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline, azure-pipelines-build-task

We have a Release Pipeline that is being trigger after a build pipeline is succeded.

We have been updating the build pipeline and adding additional stages to it that does not affect the Release process. The problem is, that sometimes the additional stages are failing, causing the Release pipeline not to be trigger, but the original initial stage is succeded and the release could still be done.

[image]

Is there a way to set up the Release Pipeline to trigger after the Build Initial Stage succeded? I can only find the build, but would be ideal to set the stage too.

Answer (score 1):

You can use for instance extension [Trigger Azure DevOps Pipeline](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=maikvandergaag.maikvandergaag-trigger-pipeline).

You can third stage

- initial stage
- additional stage - this should go when initial stage succedded
- trigger stage - this should go when additional stage failed